# How to Send a Glympse from the Automate App

Tags: android-activity, glympse

From the app [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate), I would like to send a [Glympse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate).  Automate's `App Start` block takes the following inputs.  I assume not all of them have to be specified.

- Package
- Activity Class
- Action
- Data URI
- Mime Type
- Category
- Extras
- Flags

What should I set for the above values?

I am reading some [code](https://github.com/Glympse/glympse-app-sdk/blob/master/Android/GlympseIntentsLib/src/com/glympse/android/intent/Common.java) and looking at some [documentation](https://developer.glympse.com/docs/core/app/intents/reference).  I figured out that the `Package` should be `com.glympse.android.glympse` and the `Activity Class` should be `com.glympse.android.intent.Create`.  The `extras` input should be set to a dictionary object.  The dictionary should have a `message` key with a string value.  The `duration` key has a long value which holds the number of milliseconds to share the location.  I haven't figured out the rest of the keys or their formats.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps...

- Create a dictionary named `recipient` with these keys:

  - `type` with a string value of `sms`
  - `address` with a string value of `5425551212` *// replace with the actual phone number*
- Create another dictionary named `options` with these keys:

  - `recipients` with a string value of `jsonEncode(recipient)` *// this will convert the `recipient` dictionary into a JSON string*
  - `message` with a string value of `whatever you want to say`
  - `duration` with a long value of the number of milliseconds to share the Glympse location (e.g. 1800000 for 30 minutes)
- Use the `App Start` block with the following inputs:

  - `Package` is set to `com.glympse.android.glympse`
  - `Activity Class` is set to `com.glympse.android.intent.Create`
  - `Action` is set to `Run`
  - `Extras` is set to `options` *// the dictionary created above*

This will cause the Glympse screen to show up so that the user only has to hit the `Create` button.